# ValueProvider never being called

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with **MVC 4 Web API** and I have this dummy ValueProvider:

**DummyValueProvider.cs**

```
class DummyValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    public DummyValueProvider()
    {
    }

    public bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
    {
        return new ValueProviderResult("testing", "testing", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}

class DummyValueProviderFactory : System.Web.Http.ValueProviders.ValueProviderFactory
{
    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        return new DummyValueProvider();
    }
}
```

This ValueProvider should return `true` for any key asked, so it will always supply a value to the model binder when it needs. The ValueProvider is registered in the WebApiConfig like this:

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
config.Services.Add(typeof(ValueProviderFactory), new DummyValueProviderFactory());
```

The code compiles and runs fine.
I also have this action in the Account API controller:

**AccountController.cs**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Register(string foo) { ... }
```

The action gets called fine when I call it like below:

```
/register?foo=bar
```

And `foo` is filled with `bar` as expected; but if I call:

```
/register
```

The server returns 404 with the message `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:14459/register'`.

Also, I put breakpoints inside methods ContainsPrefix() and GetValue(), but they never get triggered.

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't DummyValueProvider be providing the value `testing` to parameter `foo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([ValueProvider(typeof(DummyValueProviderFactory))] string foo) {... }
```

I higly suggest you to read [this recent article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) to customize Web Api Binding.

**Update:**
After reading the article the OP was able to discover the solution. It was that using the parameter attribute `[ModelBinder]` was required for it to work. This was because unless the parameter is annotated, `[FromUri]` is assumed. Once annotated with `[ModelBinder]` the registered handlers are executed.

Comment: Thanks Cybermaxs, I've already read the article you mentioned.
About the test you suggested, it works as expected and returns ``foo`` as ``testing``, calling my value provider fine, even if I call the API like ``/register``, without parameters in the query string.  

Still, I can't understand why calling ``config.Services.Add()`` didn't trigger the value provider, as the article you suggested said it would.

Comment: I found out that if I use ``public HttpResponseMessage Get([ModelBinder] string foo) { ... }`` it works too!
But I still can't undertand why.

Comment: Reading that article one more time, I now understood that if you don't specify the binding method for a simple type, it defaults to ``[FromUri]``, and the value provider never gets called. So that's the answer I was looking for! I needed to specify that I wanted ``[ModelBinder]`` so that my value provider could get called.

Comment: @LucioPaiva How about custom model binder and custom value provider? Suppose there is only 1 of each respectively. Does, say, [ModelBinder(typeof(GeoPointModelBinder))], call the custom value provider?